# final summary not calculating properly

Tags: python, if-statement, variables, while-loop

what program is meant to do: this program is a airline booking system where seats are booked, each time it is booked it is in a session, the final summary must add all the session summary's up and give the final figures.

problem: the problem I am facing is that the final summary does not calculate properly and I am wondering if anyone can advise me on as why it isn't calculating properly. All the code is needed and I cant make the problem shorter to explain the problem.

```
adult_price = 120
child_price = 60
availble_seats = 152

t_adult_s_s = 0
t_child_s_s = 0
t_total_s = 0
seats_left = 0


# stating values which stay constant through out the code#
while True:
    print("*****************************************")
    print("          Welcome to freezy jet          ")
    print("*****************************************")
    print("We have 152 seats avalible to be booked")
    print("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ")
    print("Adult tickets are £120 per seat")
    print("Child tickets are £60 per seat")
    print("*****************************************")
    # while True:
    while True:
        try:
            adult_ticket = int(input("How many adult tickets would you like to purchase "))

        except ValueError:
            print("Please try again")
            # if user enters string or float message displays#
            continue
        if adult_ticket < 0:
            print("Please try again to book with postive number")
            # if user tries to enter a minus number this message is displayed#
            continue
        else:
            break
    while True:
        try:
            child_ticket = int(input("How many child tickets would you like to purchase "))

        except ValueError:
            print("Please try again")
            continue
        if child_ticket < 0:
            print("Please try again to book with postive numbers")
            continue
        else:
            break
    total_ticket = adult_ticket + child_ticket
    if total_ticket > 152:
        # if user tries to purchase more than 152 tickets this message is displayed#
        print("We are not able to sell you that many tickets due to there being a limited amount of seats")
        print("")
        print("Please try again by purchasing less tickets")
        print("")
        continue
    else:

        print("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  ")
        print("")
        print("             Session summary       ")
        print("The amount of adult tickets purhcased is", adult_ticket)
        print("The amount of child tickets purchased is", child_ticket)
        total_tickets_purchased = (adult_ticket + child_ticket)
        print("The total tickets purchased is", total_tickets_purchased)
        print("****************************************************")
        adult_cost = adult_price * adult_ticket
        # works out total cost of adult tickets#
        child_cost = child_price * child_ticket
        # works out total cost of child tickets#
        total_cost = adult_cost + child_cost
        print("The total cost of adult ticket is", adult_cost)
        print("The total cost of child tickets is", child_cost)
        print("The total cost of the tickets is", total_cost)
        seats_left = availble_seats - child_ticket - adult_ticket
        # works out how many seats are remaining#
        print("The remaining seats left is", seats_left)
        t_adult_s_s = t_adult_s_s + adult_ticket
        t_child_s_s= t_child_s_s + child_ticket
        t_total_s = t_adult_s_s + t_child_s_s
        seats_left = seats_left - t_total_s
        t_adult =adult_ticket * adult_price
        t_child =child_ticket * child_price
        t_total=t_adult + t_child
    # ask if user wants to continue if they do show final summary if not carry on asking
    question = input("press 's' if you want to stop press any other key to continue ")
    if question == 's':
        break
print("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ")
print("")
print("             final summary       ")
print("The total amount of adult seats sold is", t_adult_s_s)
print("The total amount of adult seats sold is", t_child_s_s)
print("The total amount of seats sold is", t_total_s)
print("***************************************************")
print("Seats left is",seats_left)
print("Total price for adult seats sold is", t_adult)
print("Total price for child seats sold is",t_child)
print("Total price for seats sold is",t_total)
print("END")
```

Answer (score 1):

The bug there is where you are working out the total price for adult seats sold, and that for child seats (lines 81 and 82 of the code block you posted).

This is what you're currently doing:

```py
t_adult_s_s = t_adult_s_s + adult_ticket
t_child_s_s = t_child_s_s + child_ticket
t_total_s = t_adult_s_s + t_child_s_s
seats_left = seats_left - t_total_s

# this is where the bug starts
t_adult = adult_ticket * adult_price
t_child = child_ticket * child_price
# this is where the bug ends

t_total=t_adult + t_child
```

You're multiplying the number of adult tickets **from the last session** by the price of adult tickets, and multiplying the number of adult tickets **from the last session** by the price of child tickets.

What you want to do, instead, is multiply the number of adult and adult tickets (accumulated from all previous sessions) respectively.

Like this:

```py
t_adult_s_s = t_adult_s_s + adult_ticket
t_child_s_s = t_child_s_s + child_ticket
t_total_s = t_adult_s_s + t_child_s_s
seats_left = seats_left - t_total_s

# this is where the change starts
t_adult = t_adult_s_s * adult_price
t_child = t_child_s_s * child_price
# this is where the change ends

t_total = t_adult + t_child
```

Comment: thank your helping but now theres a problem with seats_left its not giving the right amount of seats left, I cant seem to figure out what im doing wrong. thank you again for helping.

Comment: Similar bug. Where you're calculating total number of seats left (line 74 of original code), you're subtracting the number of child and adult tickets from the current session. You should be subtracting what was accumulated over time. That is `seats_left = availble_seats - t_adult_s_s - t_child_s_s`. And now you'll have to move this line five places down, so it comes after you've calculated `t_adult_s_s` and `t_child_s_s`.

Comment: Check @Anastasiia's answer for more insight into your code.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the other bug, you are subtracting count of purchased seats from total about twice:

```
    # here you calculate how many seats left
    seats_left = availble_seats - child_ticket - adult_ticket
    print("The remaining seats left is", seats_left)
    t_adult_s_s = t_adult_s_s + adult_ticket
    t_child_s_s= t_child_s_s + child_ticket
    t_total_s = t_adult_s_s + t_child_s_s

    # and here one more time
    seats_left = seats_left - t_total_s
```

When executing your code once, I got:

```
...
The remaining seats left is 147
press 's' if you want to stop press any other key to continue s
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

             final summary       
....
Seats left is 142
```

Advice how to make code easy to read - break it down to functions, which you can reuse. For example:

```
adult_price = 120
child_price = 60
availble_seats = 152

t_adult_s_s = 0
t_child_s_s = 0
t_total_s = 0
seats_left = 0


def get_count_sets(name):
    # while True:
    while True:
        try:
            ticket = int(input("How many %s tickets would you like to purchase " % name))

        except ValueError:
            print("Please try again")
            # if user enters string or float message displays#
            continue
        if ticket < 0:
            print("Please try again to book with postive number")
            # if user tries to enter a minus number this message is displayed#
            continue
        else:
            return ticket


# stating values which stay constant through out the code#
while True:
    print("*****************************************")
    print("          Welcome to freezy jet          ")
    print("*****************************************")
    print("We have 152 seats avalible to be booked")
    print("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ")
    print("Adult tickets are £120 per seat")
    print("Child tickets are £60 per seat")
    print("*****************************************")
    # while True:
    adult_ticket = get_count_sets("adult")
    child_ticket= get_count_sets("child")
    total_ticket = adult_ticket + child_ticket
    ....
```

Comment: Nice catch, there! +1

Comment: I tried trying to understand the def and I tried implementing it into my work but it didn't work, can you go into more detail to help me understand more? sorry I'm new to python.